# Low battery indicator with LED

Tags: led, batteries, circuit-design, indicator

I have an existing circuit powered with a 3.7V LiPo battery. To indicate when the battery is under 3V, I wanted to add an LED which shows me to charge the battery.

The circuit has to be very small.

I searched for circuits on the internet but they mostly had rather complicated circuits and not suited for my system. I need it to show me only when the battery is under 3V. It doesn't need to be adjustable. What  would the circuit look like? I saw many circuits with ICs and transistors. I didn't get how to choose the right components for my task.

Comment: The LED will add a load to the rapidly depleting battery and accelerate it towards full discharge so wouldn't a flashing led (50:1 duty cycle) be better i.e. on for 0.1 seconds and off for 5 seconds?

Comment: Far more foolproof to have the LED flash to show the battery is ok like they do with smoke alarms.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic circuit that you can adjust with R1 when you want your LED to light up when the voltage decrease.

- D1 is a Zener diode, you can use something between 1-2.5V with low leakage.
- R1 is a trim-pot that you can adjust.
- OA1 needs to be chosen to fit your supply range and has enough current output to supply the led.
- Use a low current LED like 1-2mA.
- You can add an NPN transistor after OA1 if you need more current for the LED.
- R2 has to be big enough not to deplete the battery, but small enough so that the leakage current of D1 is not significant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsSrbE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, in order to save power you could make use of a flashing LED which is activated if the battery voltage drops below 3V.

Here is small simulation:

[image: circuit]

Basically it consists of a 2.5V reference voltage (TL431) and a small logic for turning the astable multivibrator circuit on and off.

How it works:

**If the supply voltage is above 3V**

- The cathode end of the TL431 will pull the gate of \$M_2\$ to ground
- Fet \$M_1\$ and \$M_2\$ will be turned off
- Astable multivibrator is disconnected from the supply
- Quiescent current is very small

**If the supply voltage is below 3V**

- The cathode end of the TL431 acts as a open collector
- Fet \$M_1\$ and \$M_2\$ will be turned on
- Astable multivibrator is connected to the supply
- The frequency at which the LED flashes can be adjusted by capacitors \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ and resistors \$R_9\$ and \$R_8\$.

If you really want to keep the LED on all the time, you could replace the multivibrator with a joule thief circuit, but it causes the battery to be depleted rather quickly:

[image: circuit_2]